# How to make update query using data from two another tables (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

1. manager with columns:

id serial PK

money int

2. facilities_work_data with columns:

id serial PK

income integer

3. manager_facilities with colunns:

id serial PK

manager_id references manager(id)

facilities_work_data_id references facilities_work_data(id)

The aim is to update all manager table rows by adding to manager.money column the value from facilities_work_data.income which in turn has to have id column selected as:

```
SELECT facilities_work_data_id  from manager_facilities WHERE manager.id = manager_facilities.manager_id
```

At least I found the following request:

```
UPDATE A AS a SET money = a.money + b.income FROM B AS b WHERE b.a_id = a.id
```

But its not my case, seems like I need one more join.

Could you help with such a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data from two tables and add the conditions in the where clause like below

```
update manager M
set money = money + FWD.income
FROM manager_facilities MF,  facilities_work_data FWD
WHERE  M.id = MF.manager_id
AND MF.facilities_work_data_id = FWD.id
```